# Access DateDiff In Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query where a previous day's balances are supposed to be subtracted from the current day's balances. Here is my SQL

```
   SELECT [206_Src_045].[Eff Date], [103_Wire_Log].[Eff Date], [103_Wire_Log].Portfolio, [206_Src_045].Activity, [206_Src_045].[SumOfUSD Balance] AS Today_Amount, [103_Wire_Log].Balance AS Yesterday_Amount, Format([Today_Amount]-[Yesterday_Amount],"Fixed") AS Difference
FROM 206_Src_045 INNER JOIN (103_Wire_Log INNER JOIN (54_Port_Activity INNER JOIN 205_Wire_Details_Clean ON [54_Port_Activity].MetlifePortCode = [205_Wire_Details_Clean].Portfolio) ON [103_Wire_Log].Portfolio = [205_Wire_Details_Clean].Portfolio) ON [206_Src_045].Activity = [54_Port_Activity].ActivityCode
WHERE ((([206_Src_045].[Eff Date])=DMax("[Eff Date]","206_Src_045")) AND ((DateDiff('d',[206_Src_045].[Eff Date],[103_Wire_Log].[Eff Date]))="1") AND (([205_Wire_Details_Clean].Negative)=IIf([206_Src_045].[SumOfUSD Balance]-[103_Wire_Log].[Balance]<0,"Yes","No")));
```

((DateDiff('d',[206_Src_045].[Eff Date],[103_Wire_Log].[Eff Date]))= "1"

Changes the output from

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  206_Src_045.Eff   |     103_Wire_Log.Eff Date      |     Portfolio      |      Activity      |     Today_Amount      |         Yesterday_Amount         |      Difference       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         06/15/2017 | 06/13/2017                     | 7TZ                | 4200007025         |                -10000 | 21770.83                         | -31770.83             |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         06/15/2017 | 06/14/2017                     | 7TZ                | 4200007025         |                -10000 | 1000                             | -11000.00             |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To nothing, when the second line, with dates 6/15/2017 and 6/14/2017, is the correct output. How am I using it wrong? I used it in a similar fashion in another query correctly.

Comment: I don't think it should effect the actual results since numbers are usually converted to strings automatically, but you don't need quotes around the value `1`, since DateDiff returns a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the order of your dates. DateDiff will return a negative number if the dates are in the reverse order. To resolve the issues, either wrap the call in Abs() like `Abs(DateDiff(...)) = 1` or use `DateDiff(...) In (-1, 1)`

A final debugging hint: It can be worth putting a problematic expression in the select clause so that you can actually see the values that an expression is returning: `SELECT DateDiff('d',[206_Src_045].[Eff Date],[103_Wire_Log].[Eff Date]) As ElapsedDays, ...` This would have revealed a value of `-1`.